# How to put the extracted user ID in the textfield in mern stack

Tags: reactjs, mern

- I am building a website using MERN Stack. I have this data on the url `http://localhost:3000/5f539fbf8e7b1c16806a863f%20/new_appointment`, where `5f539fbf8e7b1c16806a863f` is the unique id. I want to return that id in a label or a textfield.

**SOLVED**
used `this.props.match.params.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to get that but I would prefer to this way.

```
const url ="http://localhost:3000/5f539fbf8e7b1c16806a863f%20/new_appointment"

const idMix = url.split("/")[3]

const id = idMix.split("%")[0]
```

I hope it solved your queries.

Comment: everytime the url is not gonna be same it depends on the user i have clicked on.. So i have used props and used this ```this.props.match.params.id```